# Nested Table with nested td children without headers to Json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

Hi I need help to convert to JSON

```
    <table>
    <thead>
            <tr >
                <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
                <th class="product-name">Product</th>
                <th class="product-price">Price</th>
                <th class="product-qty">Quantity</th>
            
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

      <tr class="cart_item">
<td>
  <a href=""class="prod">3way Connector Cable</a>
  <a href=""class="cat">Tech</a>
  <a href="" class="code">1245</a>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="price">14.99</span>
</td>
<td>
      <span class="qty">2</span>
</td>
      </tr>
  <tr class="cart_item">
<td>
  <a href=""class="prod">Red Shirt</a>
  <a href=""class="cat">Clothes</a>
  <a href="" class="code">5431</a>
</td>
<td>
  <span class="price">10.99</span>
</td>
<td>
          <span class="qty">1</span>
</td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btnTableToJson" type="button" value="To JSON" />

              my code so far 
 function CreateJson() {
    
    var quoteDetails = [];
    var $headers =  $("thead tr").find("th.product-name, th.product-price, th.product-qty"); 
    //console.log($headers);
    var $rows = $("tbody .cart_item").each(function(index) {
      $cells = $(this).find(".prod,.price, .qty");
      quoteDetails[index] = {};
    
    //console.log(quoteDetails[index]);
      $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
      quoteDetails[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();

      });    
    });
var myObj = {};
myObj.quoteDetails = quoteDetails;
console.log(quoteDetails)
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));

           results 
          {"quoteDetails":
```

[{"Product":"3way Connector Cable","Price":"14.99","Quantity":"2"},
{"Product":"Red Shirt","Price":"10.99","Quantity":"1"}]}

But I need all the  to be added as to the json as key:pair like this:

{"quoteDetails":
[{"Product":"3way Connector Cable","Price":"14.99","Quantity":"2", "category": "Tech", "code": "1245"},
{"Product":"Red Shirt","Price":"10.99","Quantity":"1", "category": "Clothes", "code": "5431"}}]}
Challenge the other remaining a tag don't have header and they need to be looped through and added to each json object
I don't have a lot of liberty in changing the structure of the tables.
Please assist on how I can do those

Answer (score 1):

Here's a vanilla-flavored solution that gives the output you specified. It uses a hard-coded `fields` object that tells the script what class name to look for to populate each field of the JSON object (`prod` for Product, `cat` for category, etc.)

Alternatively (if the header names aren't guaranteed to be `Product`, `Price`, and `Quantity`), you could use the class names as the keys and look up the header names dynamically (e.g. `$("thead tr").find(myClassName)).html()`).

```js
const
  fields = {
    "Product": "prod",
    "Price": "price",
    "Quantity": "qty",
    "category": "cat",
    "code": "code"
  },
  rows = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].getElementsByClassName("cart_item"),
  btn = document.getElementById("btnTableToJson");
btn.addEventListener("click", createJson);

function createJson() {  
  const quoteDetails = [];

  // Loops through TR elements, defining a corresponding `item` object for each row
  for(let row of rows){
    const item = {};

    // Loops through field names, replacing the className with the actual value for this TR
    for(let field of Object.keys(fields)){
      const className = fields[field];
      item[field] = row.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].innerHTML;
    }
    // The item representing this row now holds the correct values -- adds it to the array
    quoteDetails.push(item);
  }
  // Makes the array into an object property called `quoteDetails` and prints the object
  console.log(JSON.stringify({quoteDetails}));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="product-remove">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="product-thumbnail">&nbsp;</th>
      <th class="product-name">Product</th>
      <th class="product-price">Price</th>
      <th class="product-qty">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="cart_item">
      <td>
        <a href="" class="prod">3way Connector Cable</a>
        <a href="" class="cat">Tech</a>
        <a href="" class="code">1245</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="price">14.99</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="qty">2</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="cart_item">
      <td>
        <a href="" class="prod">Red Shirt</a>
        <a href="" class="cat">Clothes</a>
        <a href="" class="code">5431</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="price">10.99</span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <span class="qty">1</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<input id="btnTableToJson" type="button" value="To JSON" />
```

Comment: Hi Cat, Thank you very much, this is exactly my initial plan but I struggled to loop through individual classes, thanks for being a life savior. I changed to jquery because thought it would be easier.